# Potential issue in TListview - does not recognise DisplayFormat for TDateTimeField

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I worked out a simple example.  Display Format works for the CustomerAmount (integer) but not CustomerDate (Tdatetime).  it seems TDateTime's displayFormat is not respected by TListview.

The sample table has 3 fields.

The line   showmessage( FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerDate').displaytext ); -->  this .DisplayText works even without a GetText event

it displays the Date format 'dd mmm (ddd)' correctly.

But when it goes to TListview, it does not use the DisplayText.  But the TIntegerField uses the DisplayText correct in TListview, so there's a difference in how TListview handles .DisplayText for TIntegerField vs TDateTimeField.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable;
    BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
    FDMemTable1CustomerID: TIntegerField;
    FDMemTable1CustomerName: TStringField;
    BindSourceDB2: TBindSourceDB;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    FDMemTable1CustomerDate: TDateTimeField;
    FDMemTable1CustomerAmount: TIntegerField;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLinkFillControlToField : TLinkFillControlToField;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with FDMemTable1 do
  begin
    Open;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 1;
    FieldByName('CustomerAmount').AsInteger := 1250000;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'ABC';
    FieldByName('CustomerDate').AsDateTime := NOW();
    Post;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 2;
    FieldByName('CustomerAmount').AsInteger := 2550000;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'XYZ';
    FieldByName('CustomerDate').AsDateTime := NOW()+1;
    Post;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 3;
    FieldByName('CustomerAmount').AsInteger := 3250000;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'XYZ';
    FieldByName('CustomerDate').AsDateTime := NOW()+2;
    Post;

    (FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerAmount') as TIntegerField).DisplayFormat
      := '#,###,###';
    (FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerDate') as TDateTimeField).DisplayFormat
      := 'dd yyyy (ddd)';
  end;

  showmessage( FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerDate').displaytext );
   // this .DisplayText works but not below

  if not Assigned(FLinkFillControlToField) then
  begin
    FLinkFillControlToField := TLinkFillControlToField.Create(BindingsList1);
    FLinkFillControlToField.Control := listview1;

    with FLinkFillControlToField do
    begin
      Category := 'Quick Bindings';
      Track := False;
      Direction := linkDataToControl;
      AutoActivate := False;
      AutoFill := True;
      BindSourceDB1.DataSource.Enabled := True;
      FillDataSource := BindSourceDB1;
    end;
  end;

  with FLinkFillControlToField do
  begin
    FillHeaderFieldName := 'CustomerName';

    with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
    begin
      //SourceMemberName := 'CustomerID';
      SourceMemberName := 'CustomerAmount';
      ControlMemberName := 'Text1';
    end;
    with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
    begin
      SourceMemberName := 'CustomerDate';
      ControlMemberName := 'Text2';
    end;
  end;
  FLinkFillControlToField.Active := True;
end;

object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 404
  ClientWidth = 763
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListView1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 561.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 353.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.Width = 223.000000000000000000
        Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text2'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.Width = 208.000000000000000000
        Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
        Appearance.PlaceOffset.X = 326.000000000000000000
      end>
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
      end>
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 592.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 57.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvSilentMode]
    ResourceOptions.SilentMode = True
    UpdateOptions.AssignedValues = [uvCheckRequired, uvAutoCommitUpdates]
    UpdateOptions.CheckRequired = False
    UpdateOptions.AutoCommitUpdates = True
    Left = 576
    Top = 128
    object FDMemTable1CustomerID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'CustomerID'
    end
    object FDMemTable1CustomerName: TStringField
      FieldName = 'CustomerName'
      Size = 30
    end
    object FDMemTable1CustomerDate: TDateTimeField
      FieldName = 'CustomerDate'
    end
    object FDMemTable1CustomerAmount: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'CustomerAmount'
    end
  end
  object BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 576
    Top = 192
  end
  object BindSourceDB2: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 576
    Top = 248
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 20
    Top = 5
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of the non sense, you could have written what you expected and what you got.

Comment: Oh, and btw, if you direct the output to something else than a `TListView`? Does the formatting work in that case?

Comment: Typing noise to bypass the minimum length requirement is not only inappropriate, but it's insulting to the users of this site that you are asking to help you. If you can't be bothered to go to the effort to write a clear description of the problem, why should it be worth our effort to help you?

Comment: My sincere apologies over this. I thought of keeping my description as concise as possible, and I kept adding and adding words... but it just rejected 5-6 times but I had run out of words to describe this simple problem. Of course I can put in a lot of dashes to separate description from code, but I had chosen to be honest. The reason this site wanted a longer description is because I had put a lot of Code in (by making an effort to cut and paste the FMX (so that whoever was helping) can construct the test project faster.  Once again, any unhappiness was unintended.

Comment: @TomBrunberg in the project, the showmessage( FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerDate').displaytext ) worked fine but the TListview does not not, but based on what I understand the TListview should display contents of .DisplayText and not .AsString.

Comment: The minimum length requirement is there not because you posted a lot of code, but because you posted *any* code and we want to make sure that you spend sufficient effort into making the question clear. Padding with any non-relevant content would be the exact same inappropriate thing you did here. Make the effort to clearly explain the problem. If that takes you fewer words than the minimum, you've not worked hard enough to explain it yet. That minimum requirement is part of the site design for a reason just like the site guidelines, and you need to respect them both.

Comment: BTW, you put much more effort into writing the two comments to the answer you've received below than you've **still** put into explaining the problem in your question. If the comments are worth that much effort from you, the question should be worth at least that much effort to write in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite your feedback is noted.  Due to the need for FMX file copy and paste, it really does contribute a lot of 'noise code'. In previous threads, I was asked to include FMX text by another user in working example to make it easy for others to run the project, so I'm really still learning. Anyway, I was really flat out tired when I typed the question so I really couldn't think of what else to type at that point. Thanks for all the feedback.  I'll learn from this episode and do better. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand why your `CustomerDate` field doesn't seem to respects the formatting that you have set you need to first read the documentation on [TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat)

There you will found next note:

> **DisplayFormat** does not affect the value of the AsString property.

After that you might think to yourself: "But I'm not using `AsString` for retrieving value but `DisplayText` instead. So this should still work."

Well if you then go and read documentation on [TField.DisplayText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayText) you can find next explanation

> If the field has an OnGetText event handler, **DisplayText** is the value returned in the **Text** parameter of the OnGetText event handler when its **DisplayText** parameter is true. Otherwise, **DisplayText** is the value of the **AsString** property.

So as you can see `DisplayText` is returing value of `AsString` property unless `OnGetText` evenh andler is assigned. And since on TDateTimeField display format does not affect result of AsString property the date isn't represented in desired display format.

In order to solve your problem you should assign OnGetText event handler to your TDateTimeField and format the text appropriately in it returned through `Text` parameter of the said event.

Comment: I did read through the DisplayText property.  From what I understand, TListview displays .DisplayText contents... In this project, you can see the TIntegerField does *not* have a OnGetText event but gets formatted properly in the TListview.  But the TDateTimeField does not get displayed with the format.  If TDateTimeField requires a OnGetText, then wouldn't setting TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat be redundant?

Comment: in my project, the showmessage( FDMemTable1.FieldByName('CustomerDate').displaytext )  worked fine, even though the OnGetText was not assigned. so it seems to be an issue of TDateTimeField.DisplayText not being utilised by TListView properly.  TListView apply TIntegerField.DisplayText properly but not TDateTimeField.DisplayText

Comment: Looking at source code for `TdateTimeField` it seems that `DisplayFormat` is only used when displaying text of `TDatetimeField` value through `TField.GetDisplayText` function. In all other cases global FormatSettings are used. Why is it implemented like this I don't know. Only guys at Embarcadero pčrobably knows why. So I recommend you ask Embarcadero about this.

Comment: thanks for clarifying this. I'm still learning to read the source code besides the help file.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use CustomFormat ? 
CustomFormat := 'FormatDateTime("dd yyyy (ddd)",%s)';

```
with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
    begin
      SourceMemberName := 'CustomerDate';
      ControlMemberName := 'Text2'; 
      CustomFormat := 'FormatDateTime("dd yyyy (ddd)",%s)';          
    end;
```

best regards
Moskw@

Comment: thanks. I was trying to confirm that DisplayText doesn't work for TDateTime.